Why is client application unable to register with Eureka server?
I was trying out on Service Discovery microservice Design pattern, so I have kept my microservices minimal. Please find below the configurations for both the applications:

Eureka server

pom.xml:
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-server</artifactId>
</dependency>

Used the dependency management to mention the spring cloud dependencies.
application.properties:
spring.application.name=ServiceDiscovery
server.port=8761
eureka.client.register-with-eureka=false
eureka.client.fetch-registry=false


Eureka Client:

pom.xml:
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
</dependency>

application.properties:
server.port=8081
spring.application.name=product-service

#Logging levels
logging.level.com.netflix.discovery=DEBUG
logging.level.com.netflix.eureka=DEBUG

Although, my configurations were apt but the client application was not getting registered with the Eureka server. I have browsed through multiple forums and articles available over internet, went through multiple educative videos around Service Discovery but no luck. I have even took assistance from AI chatbot. I have followed all the suggestions but none of them could address the issue.

There was a mismatch between the spring starter parent version that I have used across both the applications.
Starter dependency: spring-boot-starter-parent
Server: 3.3.5
Client: 2.5.0
Upon rectifying the version of the starter dependency, my client was able to register with the Eureka server successfully.
